# jQuery のドキュメントをローカル保存して参照したい

Tags: jquery

jQueryの[APIドキュメント](http://api.jquery.com/)を、自分のPCにダウンロードして閲覧したいです。

例えばbootstrapであればgithubよりソースコードをダウンロードしてきて

```
grunt
jekyll serve
```

とコマンドラインから実行すれば現時点でのドキュメントをローカル環境で参照できます。
あるいはrubyであれば、マニュアルをダウンロードすればそのまま参照できました。
これらと類似のことを行いたいです。
理由は現在の開発環境が時折ネットワークがつながらない状態となるためで、今のところ避けられません。
jQueryは頻繁に参照するのでこれができると助かります。
googleでそれらしいワードで検索したつもりですがわかりませんでした。
またgithubでそれらしきファイルが含まれていないかも見てはみましたが理解できませんでした。

フロントエンド開発の経験が浅くて要領を得ておらず、初歩的な質問かもしれませんがよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/ のコンテンツ自体は [GitHub - jquery/api.jquery.com: API documentation for jQuery Core](https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com) で制作・ホストされています。

ただし、 api.jquery.com 自体は **WordPress サイト** のようなので少し厄介かもしれません。
[Contributing to jQuery Foundation Web Sites | Contribute to jQuery](http://contribute.jquery.org/web-sites/)

```
git clone https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com
npm i 
cp config-sample.json config.json
grunt build
```

エラーが出ずに実行できていれば、`dist/wordpress/posts/` 以下にドキュメントのHTMLが出力されるはずです。(もちろんスタイルは当たっていません。)

(Windowsだとライブラリ不足でエラーが出るかもしれません。Readmeを読んで下さい。)

---

ついでなのでローカルの WordPress 環境へのデプロイについても調べてみました。

1. まず、手元にWPの開発環境がなければ用意しておきましょう。たとえば[Local](http://blog.mismithportfolio.com/web/20161218localflywheel)とかがお手軽です。
2. 用意したWPのプラグインディレクトリに https://github.com/scottgonzalez/gilded-wordpress/blob/v1.0.3/gilded-wordpress.php を設置し、有効化しておきましょう。
3. 上でcpして作ったconfig.jsonのURL、ユーザー名、パスワードをWPサイトのものに合わせます。
4. `grunt wordpress-deploy` を実行すると生成したものをそのWPサイトに同期します。
   [image: https://gyazo.com/bedad37084011eca56cc3b826f4c21f2]

あるいは、開発用のVagrantセットもあるようです。 https://github.com/jquery/jquery-wp-content/ これを使えば手順が省略でき、テーマも付属しています。

Answer (score 2):

ドキュメントをオフライン参照できるツールがいくつかあります。

- [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash)(Mac) $24.99
- [Velocity](https://velocity.silverlakesoftware.com/)(Windows) $19.95
- [Zeal](https://zealdocs.org/)(Linux/Windows) GPL

など。

私はDashを使っています。

Answer (score 1):

もしコードを書きながらドキュメントを参照したいということであれば、以下に挙げるIDE/エディタが希望に沿うかもしれません。

- [Visual Studio Code - Code Editing. Redefined](https://code.visualstudio.com/)

  - [How WebStorm Works: Completion for JavaScript Libraries | WebStorm Blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/)
- [WebStorm: The Smartest JavaScript IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)

  - [JavaScript Programming with Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript)